# How to use jsHashtable to create a hashtable of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, hashtable

I understand how to use jshashtable to make a hashtable from scratch ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jshashtable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var typesHash = new Hashtable();

    typesHash.put("A string", "string");
    typesHash.put(1, "number");

    var o = {};
    typesHash.put(o, "object");

    alert( typesHash.get(o) ); // "object"
</script>
```

but I do not know how to use it for the method that I am interested. I have 1000+ JSON objects such as

```
 {
        "form_key" : "basicPatientName",
        "data" : "Miranda Jones",
        "cid" : 2,
        "pid" : 1,
        "no" : "0"
    },
    {
        "form_key" : "basicPatientGender",
        "data" : "1",
        "cid" : 4,
        "pid" : 1,
        "no" : "0"
    }
```

and I want to create a loop to add all the objects to the hash table. I want to be able to search the unique value for "form_key" and have the output be the value of "Data". I know it will begin with a JSON.parse () to javascript.

Such as: alert(basicPatientName) would alert "Miranda Jones"

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = [{"form_key":"basicPatientName","data":"Miranda Jones","cid":2,"pid":1,"no":"0"},
             {"form_key":"basicPatientGender","data":"1","cid":4,"pid":1,"no":"0"    }];
```

You would just iterate and place the `key` and `value` respectively.

```
var typesHash = new Hashtable();

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    typesHash.put(obj[i].form_key, obj[i].data);
}
```

Comment: Should alert ( typesHash.get(basicPatientName) alert "Miranda Jones" ? based on your code?

Comment: It would... alert... we are mapping to key the value